# Which of the following properties does a process with independent increments really admit?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, independence

Let $E$ be a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space and $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ be an $E$-valued adapted process on a filtered probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge0},\operatorname P)$ such that $X_t-X_s$ is independent of $\mathcal F_s$ for all $t\ge s\ge0$.

> Let $s\ge0$. I wonder which of the following statements we are able to show:
>
> 1. $\left(\sigma\left(X_{t_n}-X_{t_{n-1}}\right),\ldots,\sigma\left(X_{t_1}-X_{t_0}\right),\mathcal F_s\right)$ is independent for all $n\in\mathbb N$ and $t_n>\cdots>t_0\ge s$;
> 2. $(X_t-X_s)_{t\ge s}$ is independent of $\mathcal F_s$.
> 3. If $u\ge s$, then $(X_u-X_t)_{t\in[s,\:u]}$ is independent of $\mathcal F_s$.
> 4. Assuming that $X$ is càdlàg: If $t>s$, then $\Delta X_t:=X_t-X_{t-}$, where $X_{t-}:=\lim_{r\to t-}X_r$, is independent of $\mathcal F_s$.
> 5. Assuming that $X$ is càdlàg: If $B\in\mathcal B(E)$ with $0\not\in\overline B$ and $t\ge s$, how can we show that $$\sum_{\substack{r\in(s,\:t]\\\Delta X_r\:\ne\:0}}1_B(\Delta X_r)$$ is independent of $\mathcal F_s$?

(1.) can easily be shown. Regarding 2.: Let $Y_t:=X_t-X_s$ for $t\ge s$. If $n\in\mathbb N$ and $t_n>\cdots>t_1\ge t_0:=s$, then $$\underbrace{X_{t_n}-X_{t_{n-1}}}_{=\:Y_{t_n}\:-\:Y_{t_{n-1}}},\ldots,\underbrace{X_{t_2}-X_{t_1}}_{=\:Y_{t_2}\:-\:Y_{t_1}},\underbrace{X_{t_1}-X_{t_0}}_{=\:Y_{t_1}}$$ are independent of $\mathcal F_s$ by (1.). Noting that  $$\Sigma_n:E^n\to E^n\;,\;\;\;x\mapsto(x_1,x_1+x_2,\ldots,x_1+\cdots+x_n)$$ is Borel measurable, we can conclude that $$\left(Y_{t_1},\ldots,Y_{t_n}\right)=\Sigma_n\left(Y_{t_1},Y_{t_2}-Y_{t_1},\ldots,Y_{t_n}-Y_{t_{n-1}}\right)$$ is independent of $\mathcal F_s$. This should immediately yield (2.).

---

Regarding 3.: We should be able to argue in a similar way. Let $Z_t:=X_u-X_t$ for $t\in[s,u]$. If $n\in\mathbb N$ and $u=:t_{n+1}\ge t_n>\cdots>t_1\ge s$, then $$\underbrace{X_{t_{n+1}}-X_{t_n}}_{=\:Z_{t_n}},\underbrace{X_{t_n}-X_{t_{n-1}}}_{=\:Z_{t_{n-1}}\:-\:Z_{t_n}},\ldots,\underbrace{X_{t_2}-X_{t_1}}_{=\:Z_{t_1}\:-\:Z_{t_2}}$$ is independent of $\mathcal F_s$ by (1.) and hence $$\left(Z_{t_n},\ldots,Z_{t_1}\right)=\Sigma_n\left(Z_{t_n},Z_{t_{n-1}}-Z_{t_n},\ldots,Z_{t_1}-Z_{t_2}\right)$$ is independent of $\mathcal F_s$, from which it should again immediately that (3.) holds.

---

Regarding 4.: Let $(t_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq(s,t)$ with $t_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}t$, then $$\Delta X_t=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(X_t-X_{t_n}\right).$$ By (3.), $\left(X_t-X_{t_n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is independent of $\mathcal F_s$ and since independence is preserved under almost sure limits (even under limits in probability), the claim should follow.

---

Regarding 5.: With this one I'm quite lost. The problem is the following: By (4.), each term $1_B(\Delta X_r)$ is independent of $\mathcal F_s$ for all $r\in[s,t]$. Now, we know that $X(\omega)$ has only countably many jumps on $[s,t]$ for each fixed $\omega$, but since this countable set of times depends on $\omega$, I cannot simply conclude (as before) by arguing that independence is preserved under limits (of sequences). (I've asked a related, more general question, on this topic on mathoverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/q/413062/91890).)

> Is there any issue with my proofs of (2.), (3.) or (4.)? And what can we do to show (5.)?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need $\Sigma _n$ to prove 1. (and I dont see how you can use it to prove it), and 2. is already stated in the definition of $(X_t)_t$. Just note that as $(\mathcal{F}_t)_t$ is a filtration then if $Y$ is $\mathcal{F}_s$ measurable and $t>s$ then, as $\mathcal{F}_s\subset \mathcal{F}_t$ you have that $Y$ is also $\mathcal{F}_t$ measurable. Then it follows that $X_t-X_s$ is $\mathcal{F_t}$ measurable, and so for $r\geqslant t$ we have that $X_r-X_t$ is independent of $\sigma (X_t-X_s)\subset \mathcal{F}_t$, then 1. follows easily from here.

Similarly, as $\mathcal{F}_s\subset \mathcal{F}_t$ and $X_r-X_t$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_t$, it follows that its also independent of $\mathcal{F}_s$, this proves your last question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Please take note of my edit. I've explained everything in more detail.